# Group in SelectList Not showing in DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, selectlist, selectlistitem

I have a class that's main responsibility is for holding methods to create `List<SelectListItem>` objects.  This way I can reference these methods in multiple views if needed.

I have a dropdownlist that I think is going to need Grouping, so I did this:

```
public static List<SelectListItem> lstPersonnel()
{
    var lstPersonnel = new List<SelectListItem>();

    var lstActiveInstructors = db.InstructorSics.Where(x => x.Active).ToList();

    var lstTest = new List<GroupedCFI>();

    foreach (var person in lstActiveInstructors)
    {
        var emp = EmpData.GetEmp(person.InstrucSICIbm);
        GroupedCFI cfi = new GroupedCFI()
        {
            Id = person.Id,
            Name = $"{emp.FirstName} {emp.LastName}",
            WorkLocation = $"{emp.Assignment} {emp.Section}"
        };

        lstTest.Add(cfi);
    }

    var groups = lstTest.GroupBy(x => x.WorkLocation).ToList();

    foreach (var group in groups)
    {
        var slg = new SelectListGroup() {Name = group.Key};

        foreach (GroupedCFI item in group)
        {
            SelectListItem myItem = new SelectListItem() {Text = item.Name, Value = item.Id.ToString(), Group = slg};
            lstPersonnel.Add(myItem);
        }
    }

    return lstPersonnel;
}
```

In my controller I have this:

```
ViewBag.InstrucSelect = new SelectList(SelectListMethods.lstPersonnel(), "Value", "Text", "Group", null, null);
```

In my view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.InstrucSICId, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.InstrucSelect, "-- Select --", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

When I run this, I see all names in the dropdownlist, but the Grouping is just `System.Web.Mvc.SelectListGroup`.  Why are the Value, and Text values working but not the grouping?

Answer (score 0):

I have figured this out.  For some reason if I try and call that method within a new SelectList object like I was doing, then the Grouping would not work.

But I changed the line in my controller from:

```
ViewBag.InstrucSelect = new SelectList(SelectListMethods.lstPersonnel(), "Value", "Text", "Group", null, null);
```

To:

```
ViewBag.InstrucSelect = SelectListMethods.lstPersonnel();
```

And now it works.  Even though this is a question within an answer (answering a question with a question), why does Grouping not work when calling the method as the IEnumerable overload within a new SelectList object, but the Value and Text values do?